# Animation only for hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to do some trick with my post information.
When I hover mouse on one element - all elements became active.

How can I made this animation only to hovered element?
Tried it:

```
$('.post-pic-holder').find('.post-info').hover(function(){
 $(this).animate({bottom:'0'},200);
},function(){
 $(this).animate({bottom:'-30px'},200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fresa150/8ftnF/

Comment: use $(this).find('.post-info').animate(....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to target specific descendant, e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post-pic-holder').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.post-info').animate({bottom:'0'},200);
    },function(){
        $(this).find('.post-info').animate({bottom:'-30px'},200);
    });
});
```

### --DEMO--

FYI, jQuery `hover` method accepts in/out handler:

```
$('.post-pic-holder').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).find('.post-info').animate({
        bottom: e.type === "mouseenter" ? 0 : -30
    }, 200);
});
```

### --DEMO--

But could be done only in CSS for browser which [support CSS3 transition](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions):

```
.post-info {    
    transition: bottom 200ms;
}
.post-pic-holder:hover .post-info {
    bottom: 0;    
}
```

### --DEMO CSS--

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.post-pic-holder').hover(function(){
    $(this).first().animate({bottom:'0'},200);
      },function(){
    $(this).first().animate({bottom:'-30px'},200);
     });
 });
```